# How to add a colored overlay in an image while hover?

Tags: jquery, html, css

```
<div class="col-lg-6">
    <ul>
        <li><a target="_blank" href="http://stackoverflow.com/users/6634978/rabin-lama"><img src="images/stackoverflow.png" alt="Upwork" class="img-responsive" style="width: 35px;display:inline;"></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

This is the image I am using:

[image: Stackoverflow-icon]

What I want is, a colored overlay over this png image when I hover over it. Also, the overlay is supposed to only cover the visible part of the image. How do I do that ?

Comment: share your css code

Comment: I'm sorry if you were confused by the class attribute in the ul tag. It doesn't do anything. And I've removed it. And I have no css till now.

Comment: but you were supposed to try something and show whatever you've tried. it's not a good way to ask the question. anyways, on my own discretion, i have answered the question. Check if that works on you. if not, please add something that you tried after doing some research

Comment: I already have seen a similar icon, but I wonder where...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use specific `width` and `height` for the parent of the image.

```
li a {
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

li a img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto:
  vertical-align: top;
}

li a:after:hover {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try,

```
li a{
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%:
  background-color: #CE6F2D;
  position: relative;
}
li a:hover::after{
  content: "";
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to change the color of the image (and make something of a overlay over it), I think you should be able to simply do this:

```
.hoverOverlay:hover img {
 background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
```

And then, of course, add the ".hoverOverlay" class to your image.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set this up using CSS for your `li'` `img` and `pseudo tags :hover`.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
<style type="text/css">
li {
    list-style-type:none;
    width:35px;
    height:35px;
}
li img {
    width:100%;
    vertical-align:top;
}

li:hover {
    border-radius:17.5px;
    background-color:red;
}
li:hover img {
   display:none;
}
</style>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">


<body>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <ul class="social-icons1">
            <a target="_blank" href="http://stackoverflow.com/users/6634978/rabin-lama">
                <li>
                    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ej4Lf.png" alt="Upwork" class="img-responsive">
                </li>
           </a>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Tested this out and worked fine. Good luck.

Tested on Jfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0ek5ue85/2/